# Java Threads / Concurrency / Delta - Off by one error

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

We've been giving code and asked to make it thread safe. Essentially it's a variant on the
consumer / producer idiom. The command line takes 3 args, startValue, min and max. 
The problem is the delta calculation when the buffer hits min or max, it seems to be throwing it off by one.

It's probably something glaringly obvious but I've been staring at this too long and can't see it - any feedback much appreciated.

```
class Bag {

    private int sweets, in, out;
    private final int start,min, max;
    private boolean full;
    private boolean empty;


    public Bag(int start, int min, int max) {

            this.start = start;
            sweets = start;
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
            in = start;
    }



    public synchronized void addSweet() {

        while(full) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        sweets++;
        in++;
        if(sweets==max) full = true;
        empty = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void removeSweet() {

        while(empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        sweets--;
        out++;
        if(sweets==min) empty = true;
        full = false;
        notifyAll();


    }

    public String delta() {
        return("Delta = " + (in-out-sweets) + " Sweets = " + sweets);
    }


}


class Child extends Thread { //consumer

    private Bag bag;
    public Child(Bag bag) {
        this.bag = bag;
    }

    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            bag.removeSweet();
        }
    }
}

class Parent extends Thread { //producer

    private Bag bag;

    public Parent(Bag bag) {
        this.bag = bag;
    }

    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            bag.addSweet();
        }
    }
}

public class NewSweets {

    static int startValue, min, max = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        if(args.length<2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java Sweets.java startValue, min, max");
            System.exit(1);
        }



        try {
            startValue = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            min = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            max = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Args must be integers.");
            System.exit(1);
        }


        Bag bag = new Bag(startValue, min, max);
        Child cthread = new Child(bag);
        Parent pthread = new Parent(bag);

        pthread.start(); //changed order here
        cthread.start();


        while(true) {

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println(bag.delta());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would remove the usage of the `empty` variable. This is a fact discoverable simply from `sweets` and `min`/`max`. It introduces more state in maintain.

Comment: Also, I believe delta should just be `in - out` (no `- sweets`) which *should be equal* to `sweets`. E.g. empty bag, sweet added, delta should be 1. However, `1 - 0 - 1` is 0, which seems incorrect.

Comment: what are the commands with which you call it when you tested it?

Comment: Turns out I need to sync the Delta calculation method, this fixed the problems. Will remove the empty variable as per feedback, thanks everyone.

Comment: Works perfectly now without any of the control booleans and a few other changes. I'll post the final code as soon as I'm allowed (can't answer my own question too soon it turns out)

Comment: Synchronization is required to protect data from concurrent access by producers and consumers. Here, the data to be protected is composed of the fields you change in the addSweet and removeSweet methods, in particular "in", "out" and "sweets".
Everywhere you access those fields (writing *and* reading), you must synchronize on the same lock - here, you synchronize implicitely on "this", so adding the "synchronized" keyword to the delta() method will work (or adding a "synchronized(this)" block in the method)

Comment: Thanks Olivier, that was it on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is Delta needed to be synchronized. As per the comments I removed the booleans also, works fine now. Thanks everyone.

```
class Bag {

    private int sweets, in, out;
    private final int start,min, max;

    public Bag(int min, int max, int start) {

            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
            this.start = start;
            sweets = start;
            in = start;
    }



    public synchronized void addSweet() {

        while(sweets==max) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        sweets++;
        in++;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void removeSweet() {

        while(sweets==min) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        sweets--;
        out++;
        notifyAll();


    }

    public synchronized String delta() {
        return("Delta = " + (in-out-sweets) + " Sweets = " + sweets);
    }


}


class Child extends Thread { //consumer

    private Bag bag;
    public Child(Bag bag) {
        this.bag = bag;
    }

    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            bag.removeSweet();
        }
    }
}

class Parent extends Thread { //producer

    private Bag bag;

    public Parent(Bag bag) {
        this.bag = bag;
    }

    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            bag.addSweet();
        }
    }
}

public class Sweets {

    static int startValue, min, max = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        if(args.length<2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java Sweets.java min max start");
            System.exit(1);
        }



        try {
            startValue = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            min = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            max = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Args must be integers.");
            System.exit(1);
        }


        Bag bag = new Bag(min, max, startValue);
        Child cthread = new Child(bag);
        Parent pthread = new Parent(bag);

        pthread.start(); //changed order here
        cthread.start();


        while(true) {

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println(bag.delta());
        }
    }
}
```